# How to Group and Count in Linq SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, silverlight

I am trying to read a table via WCF RIA service called GRADE_RESULT. I need to count the number of student with a a specific student number (STU_NO) and in the year of 2013 (SCH_CTR). This is what I got right now.

```
DomainService2 context = new DomainService2();
EntityQuery<GRADE_RESULT> query = from c in context.GetGRADE_RESULTQuery()
                                  where ((c.STU_NO == stuid2) && (c.SCH_CTR == 13))
                                  group c by c.SCH_CTR into t
                                  select t.Count();
```

I know I have a syntax error but I can not figure it out. :( I am new to LinQ SQL so be gentle

Comment: what syntax error do you get?

Comment: `Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery<Global4.Web.GRADE_RESULT>'`

Comment: try adding this namespace `using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client;`

Comment: I am already using this namespace :(

Comment: do you have other queries in your application that work or ist this the first one?

Comment: No I have 10 other that work

Comment: You have defined the return type (query) as an EntityQuery of type GRADE_RESULT.  Does GRADE_RESULT exist in your domain model?  Try using var query = from c in context... instead.